# is it possible to search all Redshift procedures for text?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I am dropping old tables from Redshift. Is it possible to search through all procedures to make sure a table is not referenced? It would be a lot easier than opening each one to search for text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`unscanned_table_summary.sql`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminScripts/unscanned_table_summary.sql) query we provide on GitHub